# Small letters as input but capital letters as output

Tags: macros, capitalization

Is it possible to define (or is there already) a macro which takes small letters as input but gives the same letters in capital as output?

Example:

```
\CapLet{horse} and \CapLet{fish}
```

wiht the output

```
HORSE and FISH
```

Comment: `\MakeUppercase`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\MakeUppercase` converts the case of its argument to UPPER CASE.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\CapLet\MakeUppercase
\let\LowLet\MakeLowercase
\begin{document}
\CapLet{horse} and \CapLet{fish} \par
\LowLet{HORSE} AND \LowLet{FISH}
\end{document}
```

It uses the TeX primitive `\uppercase` internally. A comparable `\MakeLowercase` exists.